# How to hide form submit button unless input is focussed (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript

I have a form where I would like to hide the submit button unless the input is focussed/selected.

There is only one input apart from the submit.

I need to do this using pure JS (or perhaps CSS/Sass), *not* jQuery etc.

Basic example:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Example field">
    <input type="submit value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I have only tried doing it with CSS. I would know how to do this with jQuery, but have no idea with pure JS, which is required for this project.

Comment: .... Why cant you find out what vanilla JS does ? jQuery uses vanilla JS..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the pure CSS solution;

```css
.showonfocus{
  display:none;
}
.inputfield:focus + .showonfocus{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Example field" class="inputfield">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="showonfocus">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I used - I wasn't sure if this sort of thing was possible!

Answer (score 1):

First get references to your objects, so change the HTML for example :

```
<form>
    <input id="input_1" type="text" placeholder="Example field">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

With some CSS we will hide the submit by default:

```
#submit{
    display:none;
}
```

We have added Id's, now we add the event listeners for focus on input..

```
document.getElementById("input_1").addEventListener('focus', function(){
    document.getElementById("submit").style.display = 'block';
}
, true);
```

The second param into the eventListener will execute when the event is fired..

You will need to do more work on this..

https://jsfiddle.net/7uzkzr67/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Used the CSS solution below, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onblur` and `onfocus` events to manipulate your html elements. You can try something like,

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Example field" onblur="setVisible('hidden');" onfocus="setVisible('visible');">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" style="visibility:hidden">
</form>
```

**Javscript**

```
function setVisible(state) {
    document.getElementById("submit").style.visibility = state;
}
```

**Here is the working DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/qbotxpL6/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yours is prettier

Comment: Yes.. Thats what I'm wondering.. **Downvoter.. Please state reason**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used a CSS solution below but thanks